# TypeORM composite foreign key

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

In a first class, the primary key is composite:

```js
@Entity({
  name: 'ClassA',
  database: Constants.DATABASE_NAME,
})
export class ClassA {
  @PrimaryColumn({
    name: 'Field1',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 4,
  })
  field1: string;

  @PrimaryColumn({
    name: 'Field2',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 2,
  })
  field2: string;

  @PrimaryColumn({
    name: 'Field3',
    type: 'integer',
  })
  field3: number;

  @OneToMany(() => ClassB, (classB) => classB.classA)
  classB: ClassB[];
}
```

In another class, the first class is used as a foreign key:

```js
@Entity({
  name: 'ClassB',
  database: Constants.DATABASE_NAME,
})
export class ClassB {

  ...

  @ManyToOne(() => ClassA, (classA) => classA.classB, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn([
    { name: 'Field1', referencedColumnName: 'field1' },
    { name: 'Field2', referencedColumnName: 'field2' },
    { name: 'Field3', referencedColumnName: 'field3' },
  ])
  classA: ClassA;
}
```

When I start NestJS using `nest start`, I get the error

```
code: "ER_FK_NO_INDEX_PARENT"
errno: 1822
sqlMessage: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'FK_1d19fe001872b5ee9ab545c18f8' in the referenced table 'ClassA'
sqlState: "HY000
```

I tried to alter the ClassA table and add indexes on each column of the primary key, and then an index of all columns of the primary key, but the error is still the same.

Is this possible to manage this case with TypeORM?

Relevant packages:

- typeorm: `0.2.41`
- @nestjs/core: `8.0.0`
- @nestjs/typeorm: `8.0.3`
- mysql: `2.18.1`

DB: `MySQL v8.0` in a Docker container (`mysql:latest`)

Thank you.

## Edit

It seems that the issue is that the table is created in more than one step with TypeORM. The table looks like this after the error message.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ClassB` (
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ClassAField1` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `ClassAField2` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `ClassAField3` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Date`,`ClassAField1`,`ClassAField2`,`ClassAField3`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The error happens on the following query, where TypeORM tries to add the foreign key:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `ClassB`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_479eaf779e0d5f0d0a83bb9e30d`
FOREIGN KEY (`ClassAField1`, `ClassAField2`, `ClassAField3`)
REFERENCES `LandPlots`(`Field1`,`Field2`,`Field3`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

I made a few tests, and the following query works as intended:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ClassB` (
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ClassAField1` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `ClassAField2` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `ClassAField3` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Date`),
  KEY `FK_e6b2926df2c758d8d8810e4345a` (`ClassAField1`, `ClassAField2`, `ClassAField3`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_e6b2926df2c758d8d8810e4345a`
  FOREIGN KEY (`ClassAField1`, `ClassAField2`, `ClassAField3`)
  REFERENCES `ClassA` (`Field1`, `Field2`, `Field3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The difference seems to be the line `` KEY `FK_e6b2926df2c758d8d8810e4345a` (`ClassAField1`, `ClassAField2`, `ClassAField3`), ``, which is missing from the generated SQL by TypeORM.

From [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html), the `KEY` statement is synonymous to `INDEX`:

```
 KEY | INDEX

KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.
```

So I tried to add the `@Index` decorator to the column but it did not change anything. I added logging of all executed queries, and it seems that the `@Index` decorator is not executed, so, maybe the `@JoinColumn` decorator has priority over it? (Tried to sort decorators different ways just in case).

The only solution that I can think of with TypeORM would be to generate a hash or concatenation of all 3 primary keys, and make it the sole primary key. Two drawbacks: Data duplication and CPU usage when parsing entities before insertion.

If someone has a better suggestion I would like to hear it.

## Edit 2 following questions from @RickJames

Update statement:

```sql
UPDATE cb
SET cb.SomeField = 'NewValue'
FROM ClassB cb
JOIN ClassA ca
ON cb.Field1 = ca.Field1
AND cb.Field2 = ca.Field2
AND cb.Field3 = ca.Field3
WHERE ca.SomeOtherField LIKE '%partialvalue%'
AND cb.otherPK = 1
```

Comment: Before helping with _how to_ index, I would like to critique _what to_ index.  Please provide sample `SELECTs/UPDATEs`/DELETEs` that you are hoping the add indexes for.

Comment: Hello @RickJames . The index ('KEY' in the 6th code snippet) on the composite foreign key because otherwise, from my tests, it finally works. But TypeORM does not seem to process both the primary key + \@ManyToOne + \@JoinColumn + \@Index, it only processes the PK and tries afterward to alter the column into a composite FK, which does not work. I add an update statement but I'm not sure I understood your question well.

Comment: `<frustration>` Too much of my time is spent trying to _work around_ deficiencies in the products (ORMs, etc) that try to hide MySQL from the user.  The users ends up having to understand _both_ abstractions and write "raw" queries to get performance. `</frustration>`

Comment: @RickJames I agree with you. For simple operations ORM are cool, and I wanted also to make the process cleaner by not manipulating SQL, but in the end a work that would have taken a few hours took days of my personal time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That UPDATE might benefit from some of these indexes:

```
cb:  INDEX(otherPK, Field1, Field2, Field3)
ca:  INDEX(Field1, Field2, Field3, SomeOtherField)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It does not solve the TypeORM specific issue, but I think that in the end it's a TypeORM limit which cannot be solved using this ORM. I accept your answer because it'll be helpful optimizing queries on the database.